# How to create windows service to start an exe?

Tags: windows, service

I need to start my application as windows service. Inside my application it start an another exe then it start two process. Now I need to add my application to windows service. I need to start that in boot time (automatic).Once I stop in windows service list after I restart my system It is also in stopped state.

How to start the exe in windows service in Using .net

Comment: The same way you'd start it in any other .NET application.  What have you tried?  What specifically went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use [NSSM](https://nssm.cc), this could help you